# I am looking for Ipv6 block script

Tags: iptables, ipv6, ipset

I am looking for a ready-made script that able to block blacklisted ipv6 address, like https://github.com/trick77/ipset-blacklist script. That is script is perfect, but it is not able to block ipv6 :(

Thx!

Robert

Comment: You are not supposed to block IPv6. You must simply allow what you need. IPv6 block space is tremendously huge. Good luck in blocking IPv6

Comment: It does not protect me from attackers. :(

Comment: Have you ever run a Linux VM in the cloud with only IPv6 (disable IPv4). And then allow port 22/TCP from internet. How many failed login attempts will you find after a month or so? You will find zero attempts. That shows how big IPv6 is. Not even internet bots can scan IPv6 block space for SSH brute-force. Hence I say simply allow what you need and block everything.

Comment: Yes, your answer is logic. My idea of block started about the next link - http://ipverse.net/ipblocks/data/countries/ You can see the ipv6.zones. I have thought this ipv6 list includes dangerous attackers. What is your opinion, what maybe this lists?

Comment: I have been looking for such a solution as well. To start I would want to block all countries except where I expect traffic from. With the above script I use in two ways: 1) To block all bad known hosts and 2) To only allow certain countries. I can't do that with the current script.